# How can I create a border-only bubble with CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following is a reference. 
[How to make a custom bubble shape in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527018/how-to-make-a-custom-bubble-shape-in-flutter)

The reference material is fine because the bubble is all painted white, but I don't know how to change this to a border only.

Here is the result of rewriting the following

```
..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
```

[image]

My All Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const _MyApp(),
  );
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: CustomStyleArrow(),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15,
                    right: 15,
                    bottom: 20,
                    top: 20,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "This is the custom painter for arrow down curve",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomStyleArrow extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    const double triangleH = 10;
    const double triangleW = 25.0;
    final double width = size.width;
    final double height = size.height;

        final Path trianglePath = Path()
      ..moveTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2, triangleH + height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2 + triangleW / 2, height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height);
    canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paint);
    final BorderRadius borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(15);
    final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, width, height);
    final RRect outer = borderRadius.toRRect(rect);
    canvas.drawRRect(outer, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

How can I create a border-only bubble with CustomPainter?
[image]

It looks like I should use arcToPoint or quadraticBezierTo instead of Rect or RRect, but I don't know how exactly to write it in this case.
[How to create a button with Custom Painter in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572410/how-to-create-a-button-with-custom-painter-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out how to use arcToPoint and solved.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const _MyApp(),
  );
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: CustomStyleArrow(),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15,
                    right: 15,
                    bottom: 20,
                    top: 20,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "This is the custom painter for arrow down curve",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomStyleArrow extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    const double triangleH = 10;
    const double triangleW = 25.0;
    final double width = size.width;
    final double height = size.height;

    final Path trianglePath = Path()
      ..moveTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2, triangleH + height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2 + triangleW / 2, height)
      ..lineTo(width - 15, height)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(width, height - 15), radius: const Radius.circular(15), clockwise: false)
      ..lineTo(width, 15)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(width - 15, 0), radius: const Radius.circular(15), clockwise: false)
      ..lineTo(15, 0)
      ..arcToPoint(const Offset(0, 15), radius: const Radius.circular(15), clockwise: false)
      ..lineTo(0, height - 15)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(15, height), radius: const Radius.circular(15), clockwise: false)
      ..lineTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height);

    canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]